# How to recover "lost" ZWave device on Samsung Smartthings

Tags: samsung-smartthings, zwave

I have added a new ZWave device on my Samsung Smartthings Hub v3. At first, everything worked fine, but then the device disappeared.

The device is not in any home or room. 
However, if I go into the SmartThings Hub Device from the SmartThings app, I see it under Connected Devices but not in any room.

Is there anyway to recover this device?